# Azure function Linux consumption plan bitness

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans

I couldn't find the bitness of Azure Function when running on an **Linux** Consumption Service Plan. Is it x64? Where can I get this info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***You can check the bit you are using by navigating to the details below by using below link:***

**https://resources.azure.com/**

- ***Firstly, Find your function app***
- ***Then Click on config***
- ***Then click on web***

[image]

- ***You will be able to find the property `"use32BitWorkerProcess": false`
  If it set to false then it means it is 64 bit. In case it is true then it will be 32 bit***
- ***As per the test at my end **Linux** Consumption Service Plan is 32 bit***
- ***But it may vary, depending on what language we have selected.***